# Get permanent certificate to access to kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kops

I have setup a cluster on AWS using kops. I want to connect to the cluster from my local machine.

I have to do `cat ~/.kube/config`, copy the content and replace it with my local kube config to access to the cluster.

The problem is that it expires after certain amount of time. Is there a way to get permanent access to the cluster?

Comment: Note:  this is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you can get permanent access to the cluster, but based on official `kOps` [documentation](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/cli/kops_update_cluster/) you can just run `kops update cluster` command with `--admin={duration}` flag and set expire time to a very big value.

For example - let set it for almost 10 years:

```
kops update cluster {your-cluster-name} --admin=87599h --yes
```

Then just copy as usual your config file to the client.

Based on official [release notes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/releases/1.19-NOTES.md), to back to the previous behaviour just use value `87600h`.

Comment: Worth mentioning, the reason for the short TTL is that, as these certs are hard to revoke, you will have a problem if use of these certs are widespread.